# How to check if function returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web form that submits if my function validate form returns true in that function i wrote an if statement that if another function called usernamecheck returns true then return the validateform function true. I dont want the form to submit unless you click the button to check the username. I know i didnt write this the best way i hope you understand

```
<!-- Signup Form -->

  <form name='signup' action="subscription.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post" >


    <input type="text" id="signupUsername" name="signupusername" placeholder="Business Name" tabindex=1 required>

    <input type="password" id="signupPassword" placeholder="Password" name="signuppassword" tabindex=2 required> <br>

    <input type="text" id="ownerName" placeholder="Owner's Name" name="ownername" tabindex=3 required>

    <input type="email" id="signupEmail" placeholder="Email" name="signupemail" tabindex=4 required> 

    <input type="tel" id="signupphoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" name="signupphonenumber" tabindex=5 required>

    <input type="image" id="signupSubmit" src="images/signupBtn.jpg">

    <input type="text" id="city" placeholder="City" name="city" tabindex=6>

    <input type="text" id="state" placeholder="State" name="state" tabindex=7>
```

This is the button that you click to check your username if it exists

```
    <input type="button" id='check' value="Check It">
```

//

```
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
```

Below there is the function where if you click the button above it checks the function usernamecheck

```
 $(function() {
 $( "#check" ).click(function() {
 return usernamecheck();
 });
 });
```

Below is the validateForm function where if usernamecheck returns true it returns true as well and submits the form

```
function validateForm()
{

  if(usernamecheck() && $("#signupUsername").val().length < 4) {

    return true;

  }

}


function usernamecheck() {

 $.post( "checkusername.php", { username: $("#signupUsername").val() })
  .done(function( data ) {

     result = JSON.parse(data);


      if(result["status"]== "Username is taken") 

  {

          alert("username is taken");
          return false;          

  }

  else if(result["status"]== "Username is Available") {

    alert("username is Available");
    return true;

}

else {

alert('You did not check the username');

}

});

}



</script>



<!-- Map Logo -->
<img src='images/map.jpg' id="map" class='menuitems'>
<!-- About Us Logo -->
<img src='images/aboutus.jpg' id="aboutus" class='menuitems'>
<!-- People Logo -->
<img src='images/people.jpg' id="people" class='menuitems'>

  </div>    

  </div>
 </div>


</body>

</html>
```